# How to load data into HDInsight?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I am new to Windows Azure. I am trying to load data into HDInsight in c#.Net Application.
I googled it but was unable to find any solutions.

Please provide me some information how this can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is with the Azure Blob API. Just point it at the storage you use when creating your cluster. Docs: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/